# Getting own EF 4.1 Code First classes to work with .NET Membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am working on a simple web application that is built with EF 4.1 Code First and MVC3. My Domain Model sits in a project ***outside*** the MVC3 project.

I have gotten to the stage where my web application is more or less complete. However right now, my application doesn't have any form of authorization or authentication. So a regular user can get to Actions and Controllers that only an Admin is suppose to have access to.

My question is, how do I get my web application to work with the .NET Membership ? Because I am aware that the .NET Membership has many database tables of its own !

My knowledge is fairly limited, thus any clear, easy to follow responses would be greatly appreciated.

After the Membership is set up, I know my way around applying Authentication and Authorization to Actions and Controllers.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into your C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.xx or v4.xx\ and execute aspnet_regsql, this will launch a wizard that allows you to choose your database and it will add the stored procs and tables to allow membership to function.

Then you run the ASP.NET configuration wizard (the little toolbox icon at the top of your solution explorer) and then configure your roles and accounts.  See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t32yf0a9.aspx) and skip to the Configuring the website for membership and roles section.

Comment: did I miss what 'this page' is supposed to be? also if people are using sdf/mdf auto attach files the procedure is going to be a little bit more complicated than choosing the db I think from the wizard, no?

Comment: @AdamTuliper - "this page" is a link. So yes, you seem to have missed it. I don't think he would be using sdf files, as that's not a default configuration

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net membership is actually kinda interesting and frustrating to an extent. To you run a tool called aspnet_regsql.exe found in your Windows\Microsoft.net\Framework folder which generates all of the necessary tables to get it running. Next move onto your Web.config file. If you started with your basic ASP.NET MVC 3 template then you should have a `<connectionStrings>` entry under the name "ApplicationServices". Change that to your database connection string. This is what the membership provider uses to hook everything up. If you look through the rest of the config file there should be sections for `<authentication>`, `<membership>`, `<profile>`, and `<roleManager>`. These deal with the various sections and settings that the ASP.Net user management is broken into.

At this point everything should be hooked up. If you select your project in the solution explorer, a little red hammer icon should appear. This is the ASP.NET configuration manager. You can use this to set up different profiles and manage different users.

Now this stuff won't be connected to your EF4.1 code first stuff at all. Instead, you can interact with your membership provider through static classes `Membership` and `Roles`. If you take a look at the AccountController on a default ASP.Net MVC 3 Internet application template it will give you a good idea how it works.

After working with this stuff for several months, I found it much easier to basically write your own. Tying things together eventually becomes a huge pain and there is a whole lot of extras that the membership provider gives you that is unnecessary for small applications.

Comment: I see people say this a lot, but one really only needs to use the ProviderUserKey as the key into their own user table.  Not very difficult at all, and you get all the goodness of the default implementation without the headache of doing your own implementation.